# Specify initial value for radio button

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I want to the "Exact" radio button to be checked when a form is opened:

```
<Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      initialValues={{ match_type: "exact" }}
      render={({ handleSubmit, form, reset, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
        <form
          onSubmit={() => {
            handleSubmit();
          }}
        >
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Match type</legend>
            <Field name="match_type">
              {({ input }) => (
                <label>
                  <input {...input} type="radio" value="fuzzy" /> Fuzzy
                </label>
              )}
            </Field>
            <Field name="match_type">
              {({ input }) => (
                <label>
                  <input {...input} type="radio" value="exact" /> Exact
                </label>
              )}
            </Field>
          </fieldset>
          <button type="submit">Save match</button>
        </form>
      )}
    />
```

The radio button remains unchecked. Any idea how I should get this to work? Note using `<Field component="input" type="radio" .../>` is not an option for me.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-reset-after-submit-forked-q6jyv?file=/index.js:359-1235

Comment: try to use defaultChecked={true} for specified input

Comment: or what about the checked attribute

Comment: Neither method will provide the value to Final Form's state.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default to be checked in the  tag.

```
<input {...input} type="radio" value="exact" checked />
```

Comment: Note if I do this, the input will not provide its value to React Final Form.

Comment: Remove the HTML markup for the input and add everything to the `<Field>` component. `<Field name="match_type" component="input" type="radio" value="exact" />{' '}Exact`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use the `Field` component properly:

```
<Field name="match_type" type="radio" value="fuzzy">
  {({ input }) => (
    <label>
      <input {...input} /> Fuzzy
    </label>
  )}
</Field>
```

This way the `<input` will get what it needs spread in from the argument to the render prop.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your component in codesandbox provided, you can see that Field component doesn't have `value` prop. I'm attaching a screenshot here[image]

You have a few options to solve this. The main idea though is to understand what you are passing when you say `{...input}` In your Field component, you currently only have `name` prop, so you can add something like this

```
input={{ name: 'match_type', value: 'exact', onChange: (e) => (whatever you need on change) }}
```

RFF could be tricky with just setting value like that since source of truth lives in the form. So, you can also use a mutator functionality of the form. [This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901016/how-to-set-change-field-value-from-external-user-action-react-final-form) a good description of how to do it